# How to translate "Personal care service"?

Tags: traducción

I was wondering how would you translate the field of study *Personal care service* to spanish.

In a database I have, one variable is *Field or subject with highest qualification* and one possible category is *Personal care service*. I'd like to translate it to spanish.

Thanks a lot.

Edit:

Other subjects are: *Humanities*, *Technical and engineering*, *Medical/health services/nursing etc.*, *Law and legal services*, and so on.

Edit 2:

It is said that I should do previous work to translate it. The fact is that I'm Spanish and completely understand the meaning of the concept, but don't know how it's said. I don't know what else could I do to investigate since literal translation doesn't work.

Comment: We are not a translation service. To address these translation questions, we require a reasonable amount of effort be put into the question ahead of time. What translation(s) have you come up with so far? Why do you have doubts about them? Please update your question with this information, then flag for moderator attention to have your question re-opened.

Comment: What is meant is that we would like to see what potential translations you considered, and why you felt that they weren't adequate to your situation. That way, there's a better chance the answers could help someone who is looking for something similar but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with the translation **Servicios Sociales**. I post here as an answer to let people give his point of view about this translation.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context. If you are meaning:

1. For elderly people: (servicio de) auxiliar de geriatría.
2. For sick people: (servicio de) auxiliar de enfermería.
3. In general: (servicio de) asistencia personal.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of articles over the internet translate this as:

**Servicios de Atención Personal**

(PCS, por sus siglas en inglés)

As a native speaker this seems to me like a good translation for the general field of study. If you try to find a translation for a more specific branch of studies you will be in trouble because those terms can change quite a lot across many spanish speaking countries.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking in two possibilities. Inside Formación Profesional (Vocational School) types you can find:

- Imagen personal (hairdressing, skincare, etc...)
- Servicios socioculturales y a la comunidad (social workers, care provider, guides...).

Also what are the other fields? Are there general or concrete?